# bluetooth file transfer issue in Debian Jessie

Tags: debian, bluetooth

I've got a problem with the bluetooth file transfer, my Jessie linux box
denies accepting files via BT, and I don't know why: sysconfig log
doesn't return any error.

The local service config dialog related to file transfer from the
bluetooth-applet is empty, and it shouldn't.

Any clue how to investigate further?

Comment: Maybe you should explain further what you mean by "denies accepting files".

Comment: I can pair my laptop with my android smartphone, but when I try to send a file from the smartphone I get a message of "file not sent", simply. No error appears on the laptop. On the countrary, I can do the opposite transfer. On Wheezy I had to enable file transfer using the bluez-applet, on Jessie I can't: the related dialog window is empty.

Answer (score 1):

This got me once too and I found out that on the Linux box that's receiving, I had to have File Sharing turned on, as I had turned it off. HTH.

Comment: Yes, that's what I've written above, file sharing has to be enabled on the recipient computer, the problem is that on Jessie the related dialog panel belonging to the applet is empty. I could operate via cli or config file if only I knew whet to put my hands.

Comment: It's not file sharing via the bluetooth dialogue, it's just ordinary file sharing. 

On Debian, assuming you're using Gnome DE, it's via settings/file sharing/ toggle the switch. That has to be enabled before bluetooth sharing as a recipient will work.

Comment: I don't use Gnome. Any way to operate via config file?

Comment: Well, you'll probably want to ask this in a forum for your window manager/desktop environment, specific to it. Default desktop install for Debian IS Gnome and since you haven't said what it is, still, 
I can't help you. I'd have to do what you should do; Google, for an answer for your specific desktop. Shouldn't be too difficult to find, unless you're using an obscure distro.